# Setting SSIS variables in SQL Agent Job

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I am running an SSIS package in a SQL Server agent job. I have several variables I need to set for production as I develop with development settings and example of this is a log variable which passes a path to use for a text file connection string. I used the "Set Values" UI dialog to set this value and the resulting Command Line for this job step looks like this ...

```
/SQL "\MyFolderInMSDB\MyPackage" /SERVER "mw-test"  /CHECKPOINTING OFF /SET "\package.variables[log].Value";"C:\Logs\Imports\mylog.log" /REPORTING E
```

There does not seem to be an error trying to set the variable but when I run the job it is logging to the variable defined in the task when I developed it and not the path I am sending in as a variable above. Anyone seen something like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you have pasted your SQL Agent job step information and not retyped it, the problem is most likely due to case sensitivity. *Stuff* in SSIS is case sensitive so variable names of "log" is different from "Log".

```
/SQL "\MyFolderInMSDB\MyPackage" /SERVER "mw-test" /CHECKPOINTING OFF /SET "\Package.Variables[User::log].Properties[Value]";"C:\Logs\Imports\mylog.log" /REPORTING E
```

@Bill's example above also runs into a case sensitivity with the provided path.

Comment: Seems like \package.variables[log].Value doesnt work but Doesn't throw an error. \package.variables[log].Properties[Value] IS working as expected. Thanks!

Comment: hey can we add a value to variable(not parameter) even if we add package with ssis catalog..????

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://www.buildingmeaning.com/?p=171

Looks like you are very close. Probably just changing

```
"\package.variables[log].Value"
```

to

```
"\package.variables[log].properties[value]"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to mark the ConfiguredValue as being read from the Executable value in SSIS package and config

```
\Package\Variable Container.Executables\Variables[User::run_type].Properties[Value]
```

Otherwise, the static value from the config was being read every time.